# ping echo request interval changes when there is no echo reply

Tags: ping

I am pinging server2 (ip:2.2.2.1) from server1 (ip:1.1.1.1) at an interval of 1ms with flooding, using the command:

`ping 2.2.2.1 -i 0.001 -f`

I am expecting to see ping requests leaving server1 every 1ms, which happens as long as there is a reply for the respective request, but if there is no reply for some echo request sequence, the interval of ping echo request packets changes to 10ms, then when reply resumes the interval changes again to 1ms. Is there a way to keep the ping interval to 1ms even if there is no reply?
I went through some of the ping options but don't find one that will prevent the interval change from happening. Both servers are on centos 7.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Both servers are on centos 7.

Comment: coukd be many between sercer one and two..  you did not describe the business related issues which you may have and want to solve by using an DDoS?

Comment: I took a tcpdump at the source this is where I see the situation. I wanted to paste the tcpdump snapshot where this is clearly seen but was not sure if this is allowed by serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

From `man ping`:

```
   -f     Flood ping. For every ECHO_REQUEST sent a period ``.'' is printed, while for ever ECHO_REPLY received a
          backspace is printed.  This provides a rapid display of how many packets are being dropped.  If  inter-
          val is not given, it sets interval to zero and outputs packets as fast as they come back or one hundred
          times per second, whichever is more.  Only the super-user may use this option with zero interval.
```

So when packets don't come back fast enough, the "one hundred per second" gets smaller than response time, and the next packet is sent after 10ms. So, it seems that flooding of one `ping` cannot be faster than this. My first simple thought would be to run many commands, this could be more flooding:

```
for i in {1..10}; do ping -f 2.2.2.1 & done
```